# Понять лексер на конечном автомате

Tags: c++, лексер

Привет!Хочу понять как сделать лекссер на C++.Анализировал
лексеры на Питон.Там было понятно.Очень хотелось бы понять
лексер на конечном автомате который я нашел на англоязычном 
сайте.Понимаю что код большой и трудный.Но на файлах из
статьи работал.Поэтому очень хотелось бы понять.Я разбирал 
его чтобы сделать некий псевдокод-подсказку для себя,частичную.
Но не понял общий смысл алгоритма.Подсказку,псевдокод привожу.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

/* This holds the transition states for our Finite State Machine
    -- They are placed in numerical order for easy understanding within
        the FSM array, which is located below */

enum FSM_TRANSITIONS
{
    REJECT = 0,
    INTEGER,
    REAL,
    OPERATOR,
    STRING,
    UNKNOWN,
    SPACE
};

/* This is the Finite State Machine Table
    -- The zero represents a place holder, so the row in the array starts on
      row 1 instead of 0.

    -- You can tune this table to make the states accept or reject different
      parameters, thus changing its behavior. More states can be added to
      this table.
                           integer,  real,  operator,  string,  unknown,  space */
int stateTable[][7] = {{0, INTEGER,  REAL,  OPERATOR,  STRING, UNKNOWN,  SPACE},
/* STATE 1 */   {INTEGER,  INTEGER,  REAL,   REJECT,   REJECT,  REJECT,  REJECT},
/* STATE 2 */   {REAL,       REAL,  UNKNOWN, REJECT,   REJECT,  REJECT,  REJECT},
/* STATE 3 */   {OPERATOR,  REJECT, REJECT,  REJECT,   STRING,  REJECT,  REJECT},
/* STATE 4 */   {STRING,    STRING, REJECT,  STRING,   STRING,  REJECT,  REJECT},
/* STATE 5 */   {UNKNOWN,  UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN,  UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, REJECT},
/* STATE 6 */   {SPACE,     REJECT, REJECT,  REJECT,   REJECT,  REJECT,  REJECT}};


// struct to hold token information
struct TokenType
{
    string token;
    int lexeme;
    string lexemeName;
};

// function prototypes
vector<TokenType> Lexer(string expression);
int Get_FSM_Col(char currentChar);
string GetLexemeName(int lexeme);

int main()
{
    // declare variables
    ifstream infile;
    string fileName = "";
    string expression = "";
    vector<TokenType> tokens;

    // get data from user
    cout<<"nPlease enter the name of the file: ";
    getline(cin, fileName);

    infile.open(fileName.c_str());

    if(infile.fail())
    {
        cout<<"n** ERROR - the file ""<<fileName<<"" cannot be found!nn";
        exit(1);
    }

    // use a loop to scan each line in the file
    while(getline(infile, expression))
    {
        // use the "Lexer" function to isolate integer, real, operator,
        // string, and unknown tokens
        tokens = Lexer(expression);

        // display the tokens to the screen
        for(unsigned x = 0; x < tokens.size(); ++x)
        {
            cout<<tokens[x].lexemeName<<"  t"
                <<tokens[x].token<<endl;
        }
    }

    infile.close();

    return 0;
}// end of main

/**
* FUNCTION: Lexer
* USE: Parses the "expression" string using the Finite State Machine to
*     isolate each individual token and lexeme name in the expression.
* @param expression - A std::string containing text.
* @return - Returns a vector containing the tokens found in the string
*/
vector<TokenType> Lexer(string expression)
{
    TokenType access;
    vector<TokenType> tokens;
    char currentChar = ' ';
    int col = REJECT;
    int currentState = REJECT;
    int prevState = REJECT;
    string currentToken = "";

    // use an FSM to parse the expression
    for(unsigned x = 0; x < expression.length();)
    {
        currentChar = expression[x];

        // get the column number for the current character
        col = Get_FSM_Col(currentChar);

        /* ========================================================

            THIS IS WHERE WE CHECK THE FINITE STATE MACHINE TABLE
               USING THE "col" VARIABLE FROM ABOVE ^

          ========================================================= */

        // get the current state of the expression
        currentState = stateTable[currentState][col];

        /* ===================================================

          THIS IS WHERE WE CHECK FOR A SUCESSFUL PARSE
           - If the current state of the expression == REJECT
             (the starting state), then we have sucessfully parsed
             a token.

            - ELSE we continue trying to find a sucessful token

            =================================================== */
        if(currentState == REJECT)
        {
            if(prevState != SPACE) // we dont care about whitespace
            {
                access.token = currentToken;
                access.lexeme = prevState;
                access.lexemeName = GetLexemeName(access.lexeme);
                tokens.push_back(access);
            }
            currentToken = "";
        }
        else
        {
            currentToken += currentChar;
            ++x;
        }
        prevState = currentState;

    }
    // this ensures the last token gets saved when
    // we reach the end of the loop (if a valid token exists)
    if(currentState != SPACE && currentToken != "")
    {// ^^ we dont care about whitespace
        access.token = currentToken;
        access.lexeme = currentState;
        access.lexemeName = GetLexemeName(access.lexeme);
        tokens.push_back(access);
    }
    return tokens;
}// end of Lexer

/**
* FUNCTION: Get_FSM_Col
* USE: Determines the state of the type of character being examined.
* @param currentChar - A character.
* @return - Returns the state of the type of character being examined.
*/
int Get_FSM_Col(char currentChar)
{
    // check for whitespace
    if(isspace(currentChar))
    {
        return SPACE;
    }

    // check for integer numbers
    else if(isdigit(currentChar))
    {
        return INTEGER;
    }

    // check for real numbers
    else if(currentChar == '.')
    {
        return REAL;
    }

    // check for characters
    else if(isalpha(currentChar))
    {
        return STRING;
    }

    // check for operators
    else if(ispunct(currentChar))
    {
        return OPERATOR;
    }
    return UNKNOWN;
}// end of Get_FSM_Col

/**
* FUNCTION: GetLexemeName
* USE: Returns the string equivalent of an integer lexeme token type.
* @param lexeme - An integer lexeme token type.
* @return - An std::string string representing the name of the integer
*        lexeme token type.
*/
string GetLexemeName(int lexeme)
{
    switch(lexeme)
    {
        case INTEGER:
           return "INTEGER";
           break;
        case REAL:
           return "REAL  ";
           break;
        case OPERATOR:
           return "OPERATOR";
           break;
        case STRING:
           return "STRING";
           break;
        case UNKNOWN:
           return "UNKNOWN";
           break;
        case SPACE:
           return "SPACE";
           break;
        default:
           return "ERROR";
           break;
    }
}// http://programmingnotes.org/
```

Псевдокод,подсказка

```
//Структура для содержания инфо о токене
 struct TokenType:
   token:string
   lexeme:int
   lexemeName:string

TokenType <ident>::=access

//Finite State Machine Таблица
 stateTable:[][7] int

//получить текущее состояние выражения
 currentState: int

 currentState assign(REJECT) 

 currentState assign(stateTable[currentState][col])

 prevState: int

 prevState assign(REJECT)
//выражение 
 expression: string

expression assign("")

//текущий токен
 currentToken: string
 currentToken assign("") 

//колонка
 col: int
 col assign(REJECT)

//текущий символ
 currentChar: char
 currentChar assign(' ') 

//токены
 tokens: vector<<содержит структура для содержания инфо о токене>::=TokenType>
```

Comment: Общий смысл довольно подробно разъясняется кодом (и обильными комментариями)  внутри цикла `for(unsigned x = 0; x < expression.length();)` (*обратите внимание на место, где увеличивают `x`*) в функции `Lexer()`

Comment: Это всегда чтобы опознать integer,  real,  operator,  string,  unknown,  space таблица должна быть 2 мерной и содержать именно эти состояния?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду квадратной? В общем случае, нет. Количество строк -- это количество состояний. Каждый элемент таблицы это новое состояние. Количество столбцов, это максимальное количество "воздействий" (или скажем, значений входного сигнала). В принципе, здесь можно сделать 256 столбцов и переходить прямо по значению текущего символа.

Comment: Ага,понятно)спасибо)